# Taking user avatarUrl mentioned in an embed

Tags: discord.js

I have a question about adding the avatarUrl from an user mentioned. I've done the code but it doesn't show the image when sending the embed. There's also not error in the console.

````
        const user = message.mentions.users.first();
        var mention = "<@" + user.id + ">"
        var userCreated = user.createdAt.toString().split(" ");
        var userJoined = user.userJoined
        const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(user.tag)
            .setDescription(mention)
            .setColor("#b60303")
            .addFields(
                { name: "Registered at", value: userCreated[1] + " " + userCreated[2] + ", " + userCreated[3]},
                { name: "ID", value: user.id, inline: true}
            )
            .setImage(message.avatarURL)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter("ID: " + user.id)
        
        message.channel.send(Embed)

    }```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages don't have avatar URLs, and in Discord JS v12, `avatarURL` is a method.

```js
.setImage(message.author.avatarURL())
```

Comment: thank you a lot! I really didn't hope a so rapid answer.